# not able to delete records using endeca partial update

Tags: endeca, endeca-workbench

I developed a partial pipeline and executed . There is no error that is generated.But record add and delete is not working, though record update is working fine.

Following is my record manipulator code (jobId is record spec) :

```
<EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="IF" TYPE="VOID" URL="">
  <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="MATH" TYPE="INTEGER" URL="">
    <EXPRNODE NAME="TYPE" VALUE="STRING"/>
    <EXPRNODE NAME="OPERATOR" VALUE="EQUAL"/>
    <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="IDENTITY" TYPE="PROPERTY" URL="">
      <EXPRNODE NAME="PROP_NAME" VALUE="Endeca.Action"/>
    </EXPRESSION>
    <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="CONST" TYPE="STRING" URL="">
      <EXPRNODE NAME="VALUE" VALUE="UPSERT"/>
    </EXPRESSION>
  </EXPRESSION>
  <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="UPDATE_RECORD" TYPE="VOID" URL="">
     <EXPRNODE NAME="ACTION" VALUE="ADD_OR_REPLACE"/>
  </EXPRESSION>
  <EXPRNODE NAME="ELSE_IF" VALUE=""/>
  <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="MATH" TYPE="INTEGER" URL="">
    <EXPRNODE NAME="TYPE" VALUE="STRING"/>
    <EXPRNODE NAME="OPERATOR" VALUE="EQUAL"/>
    <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="IDENTITY" TYPE="PROPERTY" URL="">
      <EXPRNODE NAME="PROP_NAME" VALUE="Endeca.Action"/>
    </EXPRESSION>
    <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="CONST" TYPE="STRING" URL="">
      <EXPRNODE NAME="VALUE" VALUE="DELETE"/>
    </EXPRESSION>
  </EXPRESSION>
  <EXPRESSION LABEL="" NAME="UPDATE_RECORD" TYPE="VOID" URL="">
    <EXPRNODE NAME="ACTION" VALUE="DELETE_OR_IGNORE"/>
  </EXPRESSION>      
</EXPRESSION>
```

After I run partial udpate after deleting a record , get following at /data/partials/forge_output/TestAppen-sgmt0.records.xml_2014.03.26.09.33.53

```
<UPDATE>
   <UPD_UNIT>
      <RECORD_DELETE_OR_IGNORE/>
   </UPD_UNIT>
</UPDATE>
```

But record doesnt get deleted.
Thanks,
Mayank Batra

Comment: Record add and update are working fine

Some more input : Getting no logs while running partial for adding (and i believe it will stay the same for updation) but getting below logs at /logs/forges/PartialForge/PartialForge.log on deletion :

WARN 04/14/14 13:13:49.401 UTC (1397481229401) FORGE {update}: The RecordManipulator 'checkUpdateDelete' has an index that produced a null record key. Please ensure that the record index is correct. This message will be suppressed but the number of records with null keys will be printed when the application finishes.
(contd.)

Comment: WARN 04/14/14 13:13:51.755 UTC (1397481231755) FORGE {update}: The RecordManipulator 'checkUpdateDelete' returned 1 records with null keys. 
WARN 04/14/14 13:13:51.756 UTC (1397481231756) FORGE {update}: Forge completed with 0 errors and 2 warnings.